# Close response.body() by using POJO class

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

How to close response.body when I converted response.body() to POJO class?

```
public class RetrofitClient {
   private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
   private final static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

   private final static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

   public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
     if (retrofit == null){
         retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
     }
     return retrofit;
   }}

public static class GroupMembersCallback implements Callback<GroupAdminPreview>{
    private List<String> usersUsername = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> usersFullName = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> usersIsAdmin = new ArrayList<>();
    private GroupMembersAdapter membersAdapter;
    private WeakReference<RecyclerView> mRecyclerView;
    private WeakReference<Context> contextWeakReference;

    public GroupMembersCallback(WeakReference<RecyclerView> mRecyclerView, WeakReference<Context> context){
        this.mRecyclerView = mRecyclerView;
        contextWeakReference = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<GroupAdminPreview> call, Response<GroupAdminPreview> response) {
        GroupAdminPreview groupAdminPreview = response.body();

        for (GroupAdminPreview.GroupUser groupUser : groupAdminPreview.getGroupUsers()){
            usersUsername.add(groupUser.getUserName());
            usersFullName.add(groupUser.getFirstName() + " " + groupUser.getLastName());
            usersIsAdmin.add(groupUser.getIsAdmin());
        }
        membersAdapter = new GroupMembersAdapter(usersUsername, usersFullName, usersIsAdmin, contextWeakReference, mRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.get().setAdapter(membersAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<GroupAdminPreview> call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

I read about closing response.body after using this code:

```
ResponseBody body = response.body();
body.close();
```

But I can't do the same thing when I'm using POJO class.
Sorry, I'm still a beginner in developing android application.

After my application run for some time, I got this in Android Monitor:

```
A connection to ....... was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to close it?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry, I edited my post to better describe my problem. Please take a look if you have time.

Comment: Plz provider the code that creates the retrofit and okhttp, especially the custom `Interceptor`.

Comment: @alxlx Okay, I edited my post. I didn't use custom `Interceptor` in my code.

Comment: @WilzzNic, i've updated my answer, check if it would solve your problem...

Comment: Add the full logcat of the error please

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need to close ResponseBody if using Retrofit. The Converter did it for you.

e.g. if you using JacksonConverterFactory, there is class named JacksonResponseBodyConverter, see it's code below:

```
@Override public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
    try {
      return adapter.readValue(value.charStream());
    } finally {
    value.close();
    }
}
```

edit:
try checking if response is successful in onResponse callback, and call response.errorBody.close() if response is not successful

Comment: Hello alxlx, sorry for the inconvenience. I edited my post for better description of my problem. Please take a look if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflicting Okhttp and Retrofit uses. Or looking at old versions of those libraries.

Retrofit 2 closes the ResponseBody for you